# AttributeDropdown errors (SDK1.0) in Debug but not in App?

Tags: rally

When I create an app with the AttributeDropdown, and try to test it in debug, I get an error (Attribute Dropdown: A query error occurred) and the dropdown is not displayed, however if I use rake to combine it, and then put the combined app into a custom page in Rally, it works perfectly without errors.

I tried this using the demo app (https://developer.help.rallydev.com/attribute-dropdown) and it has the same issue.

In the JS file I have:

```
 function dropdownChanged(dropdown, eventArgs) {
       var selectedItem = eventArgs.item;
       var selectedValue = eventArgs.value;
     }

     function onLoad() {
       var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                                                             '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                             '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                                                            '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
       var config = {
           type : "defect",
           attribute : "owner"
         };

       var attributeDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.AttributeDropdown(config, rallyDataSource);
      attributeDropdown.display("aDiv", dropdownChanged);
    }

     rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
```

Then in the normal template.html file that is auto created, I added the "aDiv".  - Now, if I open the template, I get those errors, but if I rake combine and then take the App.html and paste it into a custom HTML app in Rally, I don't get the errors.

The line that is causing the errors is:

```
attributeDropdown.display("aDiv", dropdownChanged);
```

Is there an issue with using debug mode with the AttributeDropdown? .. or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a defect in web services.  It's failing due to the fact that when running externally the hangman variable **__WORKSPACE_OID__** is not replaced and the WSAPI is failing to handle the default.  It works running inside a panel because the hangman variable will be correctly resolved to your current workspace.

This is a bummer because developing externally is definitely the preferred way to go.  In the meantime you can work around it by actually passing the oid of your workspace to RallyDataSource:

```
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(12345, 23456, true, false);
```

You should be able to find these oids by inspecting the page source of the app running inside the custom html panel in Rally.

I'll file a defect to make sure this gets resolved and will post back when it is fixed.

Comment: Yes, this was fixed in June '13.  Sorry- I forgot to post back here!